# Integration of PostgreSQL Native Functions in AGE

Tags: apache-age

Is there any method to incorporate PostgreSQL native functions into AGE? I'm aware that PostgreSQL functions can be invoked using `DirectFunctionCallX`, but this requires modifying the AGE code. Is there an alternative approach available?

Answer (score 0):

You can write SQL queries that use native postgres functions using AGE's user defined functions[1] and then call them inside Cypher queries.

[1]https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/advanced/sql_in_cypher.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this by modifying the code only. We need to define the functions which are calling those functions in the PostgreSQL on the backend or compiler side.

If you want to implement tan_h in the Apache Age, then this code will be used

```
CREATE FUNCTION ag_catalog.age_tanh(agtype)
RETURNS agtype
LANGUAGE c
IMMUTABLE
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
PARALLEL SAFE
AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME';
```

The other file in which this is being defined is as follows:

```
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(age_tanh);

Datum age_tanh(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{

agtype_value agtv_result;
float8 input;
float8 result;
bool is_null = true;
/*
 * tanh supports agtype integer, float,
 * and numeric for the input
 */    

input = get_float_compatible_arg(AG_GET_ARG_AGTYPE_P(0) , AGTYPEOID, "tanh", &is_null);

/* We need the input as a float8 so that we can pass it off to PG */
result = DatumGetFloat8(DirectFunctionCall1(dtanh,
                                            Float8GetDatum(input)));
/* build the result */
agtv_result.type = AGTV_FLOAT;
agtv_result.val.float_value = result;

PG_RETURN_POINTER(agtype_value_to_agtype(&agtv_result));
}
```

This is the only way for now. But it is not much thing as if you want to avoid much coding, then if you are adding something in it, still you need to use it through some library and for that you need to build again and it will almost be the same work.

Answer (score 0):

To use PostgreSQL native functions in Apache AGE code, you need to include the `postgres.h` header file. This file provides access to various functions that can be used within your code. Some commonly used functions include `PG_ARGISNULL` (checking if an argument is null), `PG_RETURN_VOID` (returning void from a function), `makeFromExpr` (creating a `FromExpr` node), `lnext` (navigating to the next tuple in a range table), and `ereport` (generate informative error messages and control the error severity level).

The functions called within `DirectFunctionCallX` are sourced from Apache AGE code. While some of these functions are modifications of existing Postgres functions, many others are native to Apache AGE.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach that can be used to solve this problem is the creation of user-defined functions in the Apache age. These user-defined functions can internally invoke your required native functions. You can define your own functions using any procedural language that is supported by PostgreSQL. Inside those functions, you can use DirectFunctionCallX for the invoking of PostgreSQL native functions.

For this purpose, you might need to modify the age code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `#include "postgres.h"` first thing in your file, and any other headers that may need to use the builtin postgres function.

For example `#include "nodes/pg_list.h"`  to use some predefined singly-linked list pre-built functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use PostgreSQL's native functions directly in cypher query without modifying the AGE source code. You would need to write wrapper functions for each PostgreSQL function that you want to use. The function name must start with prefix `age_` like  `age_time`. Inside the function logic, call the PostgreSQL function that you want to use using `DirectFunctionCallx`.